# iPhone ceased connecting to AkrutoSync on laptop with static IP address

Tags: iphone, ios, exchange

I seem to be having problems sync'ing my iPhone with Outlook on the laptop via AkrutoSync.  It is configured to sync over home WiFi, not over the Internet.  The IPv4 address of the laptop is static, fixed at 192.168.1.101, and this has worked for quite a few months.  The only things that are configured to sync are Calendar, Contacts, and Notes (not email).  The last sync was on Fri July 21.

I tried a number of things:

- Deleting the AkrutoSync log file, which tends to get very large
- Removing very old calendar itmes and large attachments to them
- Compacting and restarting Outlook
- Rebooting laptop, home WiFi router, and the iPhone
- I followed the AkrutoSync process to reconfigure the Exchange account, but the phone timed out before 192.168.1.101 responded (AkrutoSync was waiting for the phone to connect)
- I even updated Java (though I don't know if that's relevant)

Here are the details of my accessories/apps:

- AkrutoSync 5.2.33 (32-bit)
- Laptop: Toshiba Satellite A110 running Windows 7 Pro, 64-bit
- Outlook version 2007
- iPhone SE running iOS 12.3.1
- Laptop firewall: Whatever comes with Windows 7 (if any)
- WiFi router TP-Link model TD-W9970
- Both the iPhone and laptop are able to access the internet

What else can I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to AkrutoSync, the problem is solved.  The WiFi was off, so internet connectivity was due to the use of my data plan.  The iPhone often flips settings in ways that I don't expect, e.g., switching out of low-power mode.  It's still possible that I had disabled WiFi, but at the moment, I am unable to think of a situation in which I would specifically choose to ensure that the data plan is used instead of WiFi.

Afternote: Actually, one reason to ensure use of data plan rather than WiFi was to ensure uninterrupted connectivity as one moves around, e.g., when using Google Maps for navigation.  It was possible that navigation would be uninterrupted by the hand-off from WiFi to data plan, but as I was in a hurry, I didn't want to risk it.